# In information theory, what does the $\lesssim$ symbol imply?

Tags: functional-analysis, statistics, asymptotics, information-theory

In this specific paper, [Optimality of the Johnson-Lindenstrauss Lemma](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.02094.pdf),

they use a

$$
\lesssim
$$

symbol. Could anyone shed light what this means? Thanks.

Comment: Not 100% sure it is used this way in information theory, but typically, $\lesssim$ means "less than, up to a multiplicative constant". So, for example, $f(n) \lesssim g(n)$ is equivalent to, "there exists a constant $C > 0$ so that $f(n) \le C g(n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$".

Comment: Ah so it is just an alternative formulation of Big-Oh notation?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\lesssim$ just means $\le C$.

Comment: That is indeed what we meant. $A \lesssim B$ means there is some universal constant $C$, independent of everything else, such that $A \le C B$.